# why am i getting this error "Unresolved reference: titleView" and Variable expected for text instead every thing is as expected

Tags: android, kotlin

I checked code many time but could not find any error also updated android to latest version but this also not worked on the following line:

```
holder.titleView.text=item[position]
```

here's my kotlin code:
NewsAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.newsapp

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class NewsAdapter(private val item: ArrayList<String>):RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currItem=item[position]
        holder.titleView.text=item[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return item.size
    }
}
class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val titleView: TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleView)
}
```

item.xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `holder` is an instance of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, you must inherit your `Adapter` class for your own `ViewHolder` class that you define below the `Adapter` class already; something like this:

```
class NewsAdapter(private val item: ArrayList<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>()
```